# Error injecting CompositeAuthenticationProvider in Quarkus

Tags: java, maven, authentication, plugins, quarkus

In Quarkus 2 there is an error with connecting Rest Clients. For each request to external API, I get a following error:

> "REST api call failed, Error injecting
> gen.apis.project.external.v1.api.auth.CompositeAuthenticationProvider$OidcClientRequestFilterDelegateImpl0
> gen.apis.project.external.v1.api.auth.CompositeAuthenticationProvider.oidcClientRequestFilterDelegate0"

In application.properties I have a following configuration:

> quarkus.openapi-generator.codegen.spec.project_ext_v1_yaml.base-package=gen.apis.project.external.v1
> quarkus.openapi-generator.codegen.spec.project_ext_v1_yaml.return-response=true
> quarkus.openapi-generator.codegen.spec.project_ext_v1_yaml.client-headers-factory=none
> quarkus.openapi-generator.codegen.spec.project_ext_v1_yaml.custom-register-providers=org.tkit.quarkus.rs.interceptor.TransferEncodingFilter

Does someone know what may cause it?

Comment: can you share a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the appropriate `quarkus.oidc` properties to use the OIDC client.

And verify the oidc-client dependency is added:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-oidc-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```